# Getting results from multiple rows by comparing values in multiple column in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the fixture list of a club from the fixture table which has the fields of HomeTeam and AwayTeam but when i search it returns only the first row that match the search parameter. yet I want to get both the fixtures when a club is playing at home and away.
Here is my procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE GetClubFixtures(clubName varchar(45))
BEGIN
SELECT FixtureDate, Tournament, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, KickOff
FROM  fixture
WHERE SeasonID in
(select SeasonID from season where seasonType=1) 
and HomeTeam = ClubName 
or AwayTeam=ClubName
ORDER BY FixtureDate;
```

only **one row** is returned as shown below

**`'2013-05-15', 'FSL', 'Sports Club Victoria University', 'Villa Sports Club', 05:00:00`**

Comment: please provide procedure

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your version of your `PROCEDURE` you using

```
where SeasonID in
(select SeasonID from season where seasonType=1) 
and HomeTeam = ClubName 
or AwayTeam=ClubName
```

But i think what you want is something like this

```
where SeasonID in
(select SeasonID from season where seasonType=1) 
and 
(HomeTeam = ClubName 
or AwayTeam=ClubName)
```

Hence Try the Below **`procedure`**

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE GetClubFixtures(clubName varchar(45))
BEGIN
SELECT FixtureDate, Tournament, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, KickOff
FROM  fixture
WHERE SeasonID in
(select SeasonID from season where seasonType=1) 
and 
(HomeTeam = ClubName 
or AwayTeam=ClubName)
ORDER BY FixtureDate;
```